# Django objects.all() method not return any data

Tags: python, mysql, django

I just started with Django and everything is ok until i try to connect django with database mysql.
here is my problem:

i add this script to models

```
class RootWord(models.Model):
    root_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, unique=True, max_length = 10)
    rootword = models.CharField(null=False, max_length = 20)
    rootword_pos = models.CharField(null=False, max_length = 20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.rootword
```

i wrote this on views.py

```
def select_from_db(request)
    rootword = RootWord.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'ecs/index.html', {'rootword': rootword})
```

on index.html

```
<html><body>{{ rootword }}</body></html>
```

and the return value just this `[]`
(i already start the mysql service)

Comment: Have you created any instances of RootWord?

Comment: yes, from ecs import RootWord @dazedconfused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be no data in your database.

You can verify that by using Django shell:

`python manage.py shell`

and then

```
>>> from ecs import RootWord
>>> RootWord.objects.all()
```

see if it outputs anything.

Edit:
You can manually create some data in Django shell:

```
>>> rootword = RootWord(root_id=1, rootword="rootword", rootword_pos="wootword_pos")
>>> rootword.save()
```

After this, you should see some output; moreover, if you want to create data on your webpage, you'll have to send some POST requests and write a view to handle that.

Comment: ah, it clear anything, 
when i create a class RootWord on models.py, there will be table called ecs_rootword in database. so, the data should be there.
what i've done was import another table where that is the wrong point. thanks a lot for your response

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you mean; however, you can manually create some data in the Django shell. I'll edit my post to tell you how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

There

```
rootword = RootWord.objects.all()
```

The rootword will be a list type whose the elements are RootWord instances, so I think you should use a for loop in your template, like this:

```
{% for xxx in rootword %}
    blah blah blah
{% endfor %}
```